# Регулярные выражения на "только буквы" и "только цифры"

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Пытаюсь сделать проверку пароля на защищенность. Если в пароле только буквы (не важно какие - латинские или русские) или только цифры, это нужно отловить. Пробовал такую конструкцию:

```
var Reg6 = new RegExp("^[A-zА-яЁё]+$"); 
var Reg61 = new RegExp("^.*[^A-zА-яЁё].*$");
if(Reg6.test(pass1))
{
 //находим наличие букв
 if(Reg61.test(pass1))
 {
 //есть ли другие символы.
 }
}
```

Т.е. если проходим только первое условие, то в пароле только буквы, если проходим и второе, то там есть другие символы.  
На деле такой код не работает. Может возможно составить одну регулярку на наличие ТОЛЬКО букв? (И еще одну на наличие ТОЛЬКО цифр)

Comment: ни один предложенный варик не работает, всё равно можно будет вводить ^[]\`
никто не знает чтоль норм способ?

Comment: @eeeMan.rgRori посмотрите на ответ от пользователя barber, регулярное выражение актуально. Если нужно сделать и на проверку латинских букв, то добавьте их диапазон отдельно. По логике вопроса добивались по всей видимости того, что если строка была захвачена значить пароль не валидно установлен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var re = /^([a-zа-яё]+|\d+)$/i;
```

Сработает, если в пароле только буквы или только цифры.

Comment: Срабатывает на "только цифры", на буквы реакции не добился. http://jsfiddle.net/V3DMU/

Comment: У меня всё отлично работает. Вы как проверяете?

Comment: @barber - он же написал - http://jsfiddle.net/V3DMU/ 

[вот я подставил ваше значение](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/V3DMU/2/)

кстати у вас всё работает :)

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать другой подход - найти есть ли в строке цифры следующие за буквами, либо буквы следующие за цифрами:

```
var re=/(?:[а-яёa-z]\d|\d[в-яёa-z])/i;
if (re.test(pass1)) {
   //и буквы и цифры
} else {
 или нет букв или нет цифр
}
```

а такой регексп ограничит использование других символов:

```
re=/^(?:[в-яёa-z\d]*[а-яёa-z]\d[в-яёa-z\d]*$|[в-яёa-z\d]*\d[в-яёa-z][в-яёa-z\d]*$)/i
```

[пример с вашими тестами](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/V3DMU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ.

```
var Reg61 = new RegExp("^.*[^A-zА-яЁё].*$");
if(Reg61.test(pass1))
 {
 //не только буквы
 }
else
 {
 //только буквы
 }
```

Comment: test вернёт true, если в пароле только цифры.

Comment: Ну да, у меня 2 проверки. Эта одна из них.